# combining multiple validation for input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I have a form with dynamically created fields (name1 is initial, the others are dinamic), I'm using jquery validation and already using jQuery.validator.addMethod for a regex validation.

I'm having troubles adding an additional validation to check for unique values.

```
 <input class="enter" name="name1" id="name1" type="text"> 
 <input class="enter" name="name2" id="name2" type="text">  
 <input class="enter" name="name3" id="name3" type="text">
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put all of the values of the `input`s into an Array and check if any of them are the same on the keyup event.

```html
<input class="enter" name="name1" id="name1" type="text"><p/> 
<input class="enter" name="name2" id="name2" type="text"> 
<p/>
<input class="enter" name="name3" id="name3" type="text">  
<script>
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input.enter');
for(let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++){
  inputs[i].onkeyup = function(e){
    var arr = [];
    inputs.forEach(function(i){
      arr.push(i.value);
    });
    var duplicates = getDuplicates(arr);
    for(var key in duplicates){
      alert("Values must be unique");
      this.value = "";
    }
  }
}
function getDuplicates(arr) {
    var duplicates = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if(arr[i].trim().length){
        if(duplicates.hasOwnProperty(arr[i])) {
            duplicates[arr[i]].push(i);
        } else if (arr.lastIndexOf(arr[i]) !== i) {
            duplicates[arr[i]] = [i];
        }
        }
    }

    return duplicates;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I was able to tweak it to fit my needs. I don't know why I was so focused on using jquery.validator.

Comment: @dandemmo No problem.